# Bazel crashes compiling tensorflow

Tags: bash, tensorflow, eigen, bazel, xargs

I did some customizations to tensorflow and to the included eigen library. When compiling, I get this (and other similar) error:

> ERROR: /home/retisexp/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1285:1:
>   Executing genrule //tensorflow/python:audio_ops_pygenrule failed
>   (Segmentation fault): bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash
>   bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/python/audio_ops_pygenrule.genrule_script.sh
>   *** Error in `bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_audio_ops_py_wrappers_cc':
>   free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f57549c5b78 ***
>   *** Error in`bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_audio_ops_py_wrappers_cc':
>   free(): invalid size: 0x000000000141b090 ***

I had this problem with other files, and I solved by passing the bash command contained in the file to xargs (see [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3636)). Unfortunately, some of this .sh files are generated (or modified) at compile time, so in this case I cannot solve in the same way.
Where this file are generated in the tensorflow build scripts? Is there any way to pass all the tensorflow .sh scripts to xargs? Other solutions?